# Using sed to add blank line at EOF

Tags: sed, escaping, line-breaks

This sed command appends 2 lines to `abc.txt`

`sed '$ aline3\nline4' abc.txt`

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

but wanted to append a blank line before adding 2 lines like this

```
line 1
line 2

line 3
line 4
```

so tried

`sed '$ a\nline3\nline4' abc.txt`

instead got

```
line 1
line 2
nline 3
line 4
```

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `\`:

```sh
printf 'line1\nline2' | sed '$ a\\nline3\nline4'
```

which works on GNU sed 4.8.

You look at `man sed` and search for `Append` in it, the first result reads

```
       a \

       text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.
```

The weakness of your case lies in the fact that you are writing `text` on the same line as the command `a`, which is allowed in GNU sed but not in POSIX sed, so the leading `\` is interpreted as the backslash that would be required after `a` in a multiline script.

Your code would error with POSIX sed, because there it's required that the `text` must be on the next line *and* the line break that you must put before `text` must be escaped with `\`. (Reference: [O'Reilly's *`sed` & `awk`* by Dale Dougherty & Arnold Robbins](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sed-awk/1565922255/).)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Enlico. We could do this with tee very easily without using regex.

`sed '$ a\\nline3\nline4' abc.txt`

Solved the problem

line 1
line 2

line 3
line 4